# How do I properly use the strip() type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm currently trying to make a discord bot. I am trying to set it so that it will send a message in the console that (user) sent the (command) command in (channel). The way that ctx works, the strings always have a leading and trailing whitespace. I'm wondering how I can remove said whitespace. I tried using .strip, as you can see, but it is not working at all.

```
def receivedcommand(ctx):
    print(current_datetime,'INFO: Chat Command Received;',ctx.author.name,'sent \"',ctx.message.content.strip(),'\" in \"#',ctx.channel.name.strip()[2:],'\"')
```

The `[2:]` is there to remove the prefix in my server, in this case being an emoji and a discord-compatible pipe.

That function returns

```
[07/16/21 21:03:39] INFO: Chat Command Received; Vyladence sent " |parrot awa2 " in "# programming "
```

upon receiving the `|parrot` command sent by Vyladence in #programming. Anybody know what I'm messing up here?

Comment: `strip` is a method, not a type.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to python. Just started learning on Tuesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did strip any space there was to strip. `print` itself is adding the space between the `"` and the value of `ctx.message.content.strip()`.

Instead of passing multiple arguments to `print`, consider building a single string:

```
print(f'{current_datetime} INFO: Chat Command Received; ctx.author.name sent "{ctx.message.content.strip()}" in "#{ctx.channel.name.strip()[2:]}"')
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually stripped it, since you are using a comma, it automatically adds a space delimiter, to fix it try the below:

```
print(current_datetime,'INFO: Chat Command Received;',ctx.author.name,'sent \"',ctx.message.content.strip(),'\" in \"#',ctx.channel.name.strip()[2:],'\"', sep='')
```

Example:

Printing with comma automatically adds space separators, as you can see below:

```
>>> print('a', 'b')
a b
>>>
```

Adding `sep=''` (assigning the separator to an empty string) would do it:

```
>>> print('a', 'b', sep='')
ab
>>>
```